# How should i parse this value using parse.json (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the data in a div in form

```
           {"id" : "2041"},{"id":"2013"}
```

i want to pass it after creating object of using parse.Json(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

but i am getting an error

```
            SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data  at line 1 column 16 of the JSON data
```

how to resolve this error

I need to send it as it is in JSON but when i get data from

```
          var data= $("#divid").html();
```

i get it in the form

```
               "{"id" : "2041"},{"id":"2013"}"
```

i want to remove first and last string so i thought of using

```
              JSON.parse(string)
```

but i am getting above error

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Hence the error. Fix your JSON. The validator at jsonlint.com does a good job of telling where the error is. http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your json in square brackets in order to make a properly formatted array of objects.

```
var string = '[{"id" : "2041"},{"id":"2013"}]';

var parsed = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a valid JSON and worked fine for me.

```
{
    "NameValuePairs": [
        {
            "id": "2041"
        },
        {
            "id": "2013"
        }
    ]
}
```